# Changing the bounds of integration in the proof that normal distribution is a P.D.F

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Considering the following snippet:

[image]

I am unsure why the bounds of integration change to 
$(0,\infty)$ and $(0, 2\pi)$.

Are we mapping $(- \infty, \infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ since $r>0$ for any radius
and $(- \infty, \infty) \rightarrow  (0, 2\pi)$ since this assumes all values for the unit circle. Any simple clarifications much appreciated.

Comment: Your last paragraph perfectly explains what happens. We have that the radius $r$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$ and the angle $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Yeah you are trying to cover the entire plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$, with polar coordinates.  So you want to sweep $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ around the entire unit circle and let $r \in (0,\infty)$ to cover every radial distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation being used here is from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.

That is, $r$ is the displacement length of the line segment from the origin $(0,0)$ to the point $(x,y)$, and $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and that line segment.

So integrating over all points in the interval of $]-\infty;\infty[^2$ is transformed to an integral over all points of any radius, ranging over $[0;\infty[$, and any angle in the range from $[0;2\pi[$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x = \int_{0}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} g(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))\cdot r\operatorname d \theta\operatorname d r$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is right $r>0\in(0,+\infty)$ and $\theta$ is the angle and it takes all the values around a circle so $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$.